# Photocopies of vital records

Tags: identity-theft

How concerned should I be about private companies maintaining photocopies of vital records like birth certificates and social security cards?

While he is not applying for subsidized housing, my son is attempting to rent an apartment at a building that does offer *some* of its units through the subsidized housing program.  Citing "HUD requirements", the landlord / property management company insisted that he provide copies of his birth certificate, drivers license and social security card to be maintained in a "locked filing cabinet".

I think this is all nonsense and the landlord is just being a lazy bureaucrat, but we cannot force the landlord to change their "policy" no matter how boneheaded it may be.

So, assuming that my son goes through with this, can the risks of identity theft be quantified?

Comment: I'd not live there.

Comment: Pages 11-12 on [this document](https://www.ssa.gov/pubs/EN-05-10002.pdf) are somewhat pertinent. In addition, depending on where your son was born, his birth certificate might [not even be allowed to be photocopied legally](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/8200/is-it-a-crime-to-send-a-photocopy-of-a-copy-of-my-birth-certificate) (though official copies should be obtainable if absolutely necessary).